# Using a CALayer to display an alpha mapped image

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a CALayer object into which I would like to insert a UIImage equipped with an alpha map, simply by setting the layer's contents property. However, when I display this CALayer, all transparency is lost. I have checked the layer's background colour (opacity has no effect on images set using contents) and it seems correct.

Is there any way to retain a .PNG's alpha map transparency without using CALayer's mask property, so that the mask provided and the content image's own transparency map are combined?

Answer (score 0):

It sure works fine for me.
But make sure you set the opaque property of the layer to NO, and the backgroundColor property to the clear color.

Comment: I tried both of these things already, but in fact the Opaque property should not affect CALayers whose property is set using a CGImageRef, according to Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, never mind, silly mistake. The layers were assembled in the wrong order, with what should have been foreground at the back. This created the impression that it wasn't transparent when in fact it was.